# How to fill in a Command Line Interface?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I am to automate the installation phase of a legacy system, because I do not want to put more efforts again and again when ever I want to install it. During the installation process on Linux Terminal, I have to answer some questions regarding the basic configurations. Indeed, it is easy to automate the shell commands by putting them all in a batch file like the following:

```
bin/startServer destination/sub_v1
bin/startAdminInterface
....
```

However, I do not know how to automate the answers of a specific questions like the following:

```
Enter the server's IP address: 
Enter the email of the contact person:
Would you like to disable UDP services?(y/n) [n]:
....
```

Is there any tool or programming language can deal with this situation? or Is there any way to pass the answers as a parameters within the batch file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try searching the question (that you have during installation) on web as saying `y` or `n` can actually change how the program behaves. In linux try to make everything that you want it to be. Also if you are not sure what to reply with such question, either look for capital letter or the letter in `[]`, they are actually the default ones, which will be used as if you press enter without saying `y` or `n`

Comment: Actually, I am not the developer of that app, I am just user trying to automate the installation phase, because I dont want to put more efforts again and again when ever a install it!!

Comment: I tried once to do the same and in case of bash script i was unable to solve this problem. I think you have to take pain of putting y or n by your own.

Comment: `expect` is the tool for this job, I think.  Assuming that you can't just provide the answers in a here-document.

Comment: Where do you expect this automated program to get the server's IP address from? How do you expect it to know the contact person? I mean where is it suuposed to look?

Comment: Thanx @shivams, but what about the data? its not only `y` or `n`. Unfortunately, there are a lot of questions which a answer everytime with the same data :(

Comment: @Kh.Taheri I think now you get your answer and me too. Also do not forget to mark one of below answers as excepted as this will help others too.

Comment: @shivams, Yes, I got two different answers, I am a bit lucky ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic Linux tool for this job is [expect](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts).

With `expect` one can expect different questions and variations on a question, and the question does not have to be typed exactly. `expect` does not blindly answer every prompt, but rather it provides answers to the questions actually asked.

Here is a short example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn someScript.sh
expect "Enter the server's IP address:"
send "10.0.0.4\r"
expect "Enter the email of the contact person:"
send "foo@bar.com\r"
expect "Would you like to disable UDP services?(y/n) [n]:"
send "y\r"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @dotancohen, this answer looks much easier :)

Comment: I'm puzzled! How can it look easier to have to type the entire question, perfect to the last letter, AND the answer, rather than simply typing the answer alone?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I believe that with `expect` one can expect different questions and variations on a question. In fact **the question does not have to be typed exactly**, see the man page on that. If, when using `expect`, an unexpected question comes up then `expect` **won't** give it the answer to another question. In short, `expect` does not blindly answer to every prompt, but rather it provides answers to the questions actually asked. Surely an old Unix hack could appreciate that!

Comment: :-) Of course I can appreciate the flexibility that *expect* offers, but as it is a *legacy* system, I don't expect the questions to be changing much, so I fail to see how it can be *easier* to a) learn a new language, b) require that language to be installed on every target system, c) type out every  question and d) type the answer than to simply type the answer.

Comment: @Mark - firstly, cut+paste is often available, so no need to type the questions.  Secondly, the OP implied that the install is to be done multiple times.  The `expect` language is simple and small, so it's not a great deal to learn - and probably worth it, particularly if this install is part of a longer automation task (it can be a pain to keep coming back every so often to answer questions when you could be getting on with some other work).  Finally, it makes the install reproducible - that's something I love about being able to pre-seed Debian installs, for example.

Comment: But yes, if the program will accept standard input in the usual way, go with the here-document (`<<` in bash).

Comment: In addition, for more flexibility, you can pass answers as a parameters to `expect` file easily, or you can extract answers from the local system by shell commands - getting current IP address, for example.

Answer (score 1):

So, imagine this is a simplified version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter something:" thing
read -p "Enter server IP:" ip
read -p "Enter Email:" email
echo Received $thing, $ip, $email
```

and this is in a file called `answers`

```
thingywhatnot
11.12.33.240
bozo@brains.com
```

You would run

```
installationScript < answers
```

and it would print this

```
Received thingywhatnot, 11.12.33.240, bozo@brains.com
```

Comment: But for doing this, user needs to run the program if he don't know the order and type of input that the program expects.

Comment: Thanx alot @Mark Setchell, I will implement it soon, then inform you here about the progress..

Comment: I'm guessing he does know what the questions are and in what order since he shows them in his question.